# Обновление TextView из другого фрагмента

Tags: android-fragment, android, java, textview

Всем привет!
Есть два ShrelockFragment. В Fragment_map находится карта, там же происходит получение координат по GPS. В Fragment_control находятся несколько TextView, которые отображают полученные координаты.

При запуске приложения на телефоне, Fragment_control отображает координаты. Но как только перейти на другой фрагмент и вернуться обратно, то все TextView исчезают. Хотя координаты получаю и вижу на карте.

В чем проблема? Или как можно сделать постоянное обновление TextView из другого фрагмента?

Fragment_map.java:

```
package com.example.wimf;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class Fragment_map extends SherlockFragment 
{
    public GoogleMap map;
    private SupportMapFragment map_fragment;

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    public LocationManager locationManager;

    public TextView gps_status;
    public TextView gps_mode;

    String disabled, enabled, mode;

    public TextView get_latitude;
    public TextView get_longitude;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        map_fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = map_fragment.getMap();
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        gps_status = (TextView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_gps_status);
        gps_mode = (TextView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_gps_mode);

        get_latitude = (TextView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
        get_longitude = (TextView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        try
        {
            checkEnabled();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, locationListener);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("[fr_map_onStart()]ERROR:" + ex);
        }
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            try
            {
                if (location == null)
                    return;
                if (location != null && location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {           
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    get_latitude.setText("Широта: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
                    get_longitude.setText("Долгота: " + String.valueOf(longitude));

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("[fr_map_onLocationChanged()]ERROR:" + ex);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {   
            try
            {
                if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {
                    mode = String.valueOf(status);
                    gps_mode.setText("Режим работы GPS: " + mode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("[fr_map_onStatusChanged()]ERROR:" + ex);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            try
            {
                checkEnabled();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("[fr_map_onProviderEnabled()]ERROR:" + ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            try
            {
                checkEnabled();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("[fr_map_onProviderDisabled()]ERROR:" + ex);
            }
        }

    };

    private void checkEnabled()
    {
        try
        {
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == true)
            {
                enabled = "включен";
                gps_status.setText("Статус GPS: " + enabled);
            }
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == false)
            {
                disabled = "выключен";
                gps_status.setText("Статус GPS: " + disabled);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("[fr_map_checkEnabled()]ERROR:" + ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment_control.java:

```
package com.example.wimf;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment_control extends SherlockFragment
{
    public TextView tv_date_now;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);
        tv_date_now = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        try
        {
            String now_date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(new Date());
            tv_date_now.setText(now_date);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("[fr_control_onStart()]ERROR:" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment_control.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/date_now" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/coordinates" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_gps_status"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_gps_mode"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась одной строчкой в onCreateView

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Слишком много ненужного кода.
2. Очень плохая идея - опперировать вьюшками одного фрагмента из другого. Определите у принимающего фрагмента функции типа `setLatitude(int lat); setLongitude(int lon);` в которых и устанавливайте текст  во вьюшки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Попробовал сделать метод:

public void setLat(String latitude)
{
  String Lat = latitude;
  get_latitude.setText(Lat);
}

Вызывал данный метод таким образом:

Fragment_control fr_con = new Fragment_control();
double latitude ...;
fr_con.setLat("Широта: " + String.valueOf(latitude));

И не работает. Выдает NullPointerException

Comment: @Константин Пассар, если так, то прежде, чем начинать работать с фрагментами, почитайте, как с ними надо работать.

Comment: @Константин Пассар    
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html    
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html    
туториалы, по которым я начинал работать с фрагментами